# Require user to check option button(s)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UserForm with 2 frames and 2 option buttons each. I need to require one button in frame 1 (called "Area") to be selected, and 1 button in frame 2 (called "Time") to be selected before user can click "OK". When I have only frame 1 buttons code, it works great. I have yet to figure out add buttons 3 and 4. Lots of trial, error and Google, but can't seem to make things work.

### Area

O East (Button 1)

O West (Button 2)

### Time

O Previous (Button 3)

O Future (Button 4)

OK.....Cancel

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
Dim i As Integer, x As Integer
    For i = 1 To 2
    If Me.Controls("OptionButton" & i).Object.value = True Then
    x = x + 1
    End If
    Next i
    If x = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please Select Area", 48, "Select Area"
    'Exit Sub
    Else
    
    Dim j As Integer, y As Integer
    For j = 3 To 4
    If Me.Controls("OptionButton" & j).Object.value = True Then
    y = y + 1
    End If
    Next j
    If y = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please Select Time", 48, "Select Time"
    'Exit Sub
    Else

' >>>>> Rest of macro here <<<<<
```

Comment: If you require at least one to be selected, you should be using radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: They are option buttons